# How to get Intro Section Image Url?

Tags: squarespace

I have checked template file there this code used:
`<img {mainImage|image-meta} data-load="false" />
{mainImage|image-meta}`

This code returns many other attributres like:

`data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c12cc27aa49a15fa0c20dbd    /t/5c6334730d9297f6e70d6168/1550005372146/iStock-947324428.jpg" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c12cc27aa49a15fa0c20dbd/t/5c6334730d9297f6e70d6168/1550005372146/iStock-947324428.jpg" data-image-dimensions="1600x1068" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="iStock-947324428.jpg"`

I want to get the only src of the image, means directly URL without any additional attributes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with squarespace, but have you tried `{mainImage|assetUrl}`? Could you include a clip of the actual code in use pre-rendered?

Comment: Daniel Gale, I have tried your suggestion but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{mainImage.assetUrl}` to get the `src` without the additional attributes.

The `...|image-meta` is known as the Squarespace imageLoader JSON-T formatter. It is a helpful utility at times, but if you just need the `src`, use just the aforementioned code.

You can view more information about bypassing ImageLoader in [Squarespace's own documentation about this topic](https://developers.squarespace.com/imageloader#BypassingImageLoader).

> **Bypassing ImageLoader**
>
> If you would like to load one of these image sizes explicitly, use the following syntax from within an image context:
>
> `<img src="{assetUrl}?format=300w" />`
>
> In this case, the image will be the 300w image. Note that this syntax bypasses our imageLoader, and is not recommended for general use. The available image sizes are:
>
> `2500w, 1500w, 1000w, 750w, 500w, 300w, 100w`